# Parity proof of authority aura, how to detect misbehaviour?

Tags: parity, poa, proof-of-authority, aura

I'm having trouble finding the answer looking at the Parity POA aura examples, the documentation on Parity Validator Sets, plus the Kovan validator set contract solidity source code.

I see that you can call `reportBenign` for example and report the validator address and block number for the validator that missed a block.

What I'm confused about is how do you detect when this happens?  Is there a way to know when a block is assigned to a validator originally and they miss it -- the block is then mined by some other node/signer.

My thinking is when this occurs, you should report them to the validator set contract, which can then be handled however necessary, eg. remove that validator from the set when they miss too many blocks.

What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: I'm starting to understand my issue better... My nodes are never printing `Reported benign validator misbehaviour` when a block is missed, I'm not seeing the events from the validator set contract.

Answer (score 0):

I started receiving `Reported benign validator misbehaviour` messages and events when I adjusted my genesis chain config.

When I reduced my config to just having whats below things started working, so it was a chain config issue

```
"authorityRound": {
      "params": {
        "stepDuration": "5",
        "validators": {
              "contract": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000009"
        }
}
```